# How can I make Visual Studio to put default code below everytime I make a C project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I search internet I could not find any info on how to do it. Can you help?

```
/*
Name:
Author: 
Date: <automatic inserted date>
Description: 
*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
```

Comment: Create your own project or item template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page explains how to create an item template: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx

I've created a few for a project at work - it's pretty straightforward.  There are a few parameters you can use to customize it even more.